# I fail to use save_post

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPress **5.2.4**

I've created a plugin which only contains this code (except init comment):

```
function add_ids($post_ID, $post, $update){
    $a =0; // Break-point here.
}

add_action('save_post', 'add_ids');
```

If I comment these strings out, everything is Ok.
If I uncomment them, try to edit a post and save it, "Updating failed" occurs.

Debug mode and logging is on. No errors seems to be logged.

Could you help me?